# I can't show my user's table with JS,Sequelize and GrahpQL (No apollo)

Tags: node.js, graphql, sequelize.js, show

my problem is I want to show my user's table in SQL with Sequelize and GraphQL (not Apollo, only GraphQL) but I the only I get is (in /graphql ) :

```
{
  "data": {
    "showUsers": {
      "id": null
    }
  }
```

I'm using JS and not Typescript, I don't kwon if it's a problem.
My find method is :

```
const clean = (arr) => {
    let cleanData = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        cleanData.push(arr[i].dataValues)
    }
    return cleanData
}

const showUsers = async () => {
    const findUsers = await User.findAll({
    });

    let users = clean(findUsers);
    return users;
}
```

and my graphQL:

```
export const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'User',
    fields: {
        id: { type: GraphQLID },
        name: { type: GraphQLString },
        username: { type: GraphQLString },
        password: { type: GraphQLString },
        possition: { type: GraphQLString },
    }
})

export const SHOW_USERS = {
    type :UserType,
   async resolve(){
    let users = await showUsers()
    return {...users}
    
    }
}
```

I'm using:
[
express : 4.17.3 //
express-graphql 0.12.0 //
graphql 15.8.0 //
mysql2 2.3.3 //
sequelize 6.16.1 //
]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: did you try to check a return value of `showUsers` just before it returns a result?

Comment: `clean` function looks good but it's not needed because there is `get` method in each model instance to get a plain object: `let users = findUsers.map(x => x.get({ plain: true });`

Comment: First , yes the funtion showUsers return the users, and I try removing clean() and nothing, same result in graph (with return {...users}, return {...users[0]}) with the map method return just the first element {"data": {"showUsers": {"id": "1"}}} but the method map correctly returns the data in the terminal

Comment: Are you sure you need to an array of users like `return {...users}` ? This way you will pass an object with keys 0,1, and so on an values from `users` array. Maybe You wanted to do `retutn [...users]`?

Comment: Sorry but I don't kwon what I'm doing wrong... I tried now return [...users] but the same result... the strange is users is an array, with 5 elements (i used users.length)  but the same... id : null

Comment: Maybe you need to correct GraphQL part then if all is ok with users array

Comment: Bro, thanks for the help. I found the problem. Isn't  "type :UserType" is "type : GraphQLList(UserType)," =_)

Comment: I suspected something like this because I'm not familiar with GraphQL. At first I thought it was Sequelize issue